# To add UIImage directly to file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I want to add my UIImage directly into the file instead of converting into UIImagePNGRepresentation or UIImageJPGRepresentation(as it takes time) like:-

```
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
[array addObject:im];
NSData *data = [array objectAtIndex:i];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

But it is showing error.
So there is any way that i can do it.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

your use of the `array` only obfuscates that you are basically doing:

```
NSData *data = im;
```

Which cannot possibly work because `im` is a `UIImage`, and not an `NSData` nor a subclass.

What you want to do is to *create* a new `NSData` and initialize it with the content of the image. Since you got a `CGImageRef`, I suggest using it directly, without using a `UIImage` in between.

```
CGDataProviderRef imageDataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(ref);
CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(imageDataProvider);
NSData *data = (NSData*) imageData;
```

Note that it is OK to cast the `CFDataRef` to `NSData*` because CFData is “toll-free bridged” with its Cocoa Foundation counterpart, NSData.

I hope that helps.

(don't forget to release `data` when done)